# Modal view controller under Navigation Bar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have this scenario:

[image]

One tab bar inside in a navigation controller.
In the navigation bar there is a navigation item (its a button).
When I tap on it I would like to show a modal controller that which opens up under the navigation bar and overlay the tab bar.

I did this:

```
func tapButtonNavigationBar(){

     let search = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "search) as! SearchController
        self.present(search, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But, by this code, the new "search" controller is under the navigation bar.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach which I know is you can add the subview of your specified frame instead of view controller and open the same using animation.